# MariaDB 5.5 TLS handshake failure

Tags: ssl, mariadb, tls1.2

I have a database server running MariaDB 5.5.68 and OpenSSL 1.0.2k (upgrades are in the queue but not expected for some time).  I have a client (web host) system running the same version of OpenSSL.  I have MariaDB configured with CA `/etc/pki/bundle-of-certs.crt`, cert `/etc/pki/db-host.CAD.crt`, and key `/etc/pki/db-host.key`.  I have the same CA file on the client system.  Both systems are running CentOS 8.

My Java 1.8 project attempts to establish an encrypted connection to the database server.  The web server Catalina log reports `SSLHandshakeException`.  I used OpenSSL to check the handshaking:

```
web-host> openssl s_client -debug -state -status -msg -connect db-host:3306
CONNECTED
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
(TLS 1.0 handshake sent)
>>> TLS 1.2 [length 0005]
    10 03 01 00 ff
>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 00ff], ClientHello
(handshake packet)
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
read from (db-host)
0000 - 52 00 00 00 0a 35 2e
SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
error:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
---
no peer certificate available
```

To check the CA certificate bundle, I reran that command to the web host:

```
web-host> openssl s_client -debug -state -status -msg -connect web-host:8443
(same TLS 1.0 handshake sent)
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
read from (web-host)
0000 - 16 03 03 0d 67 02
(TLS 1.2 server hello message follows....)
```

When I explicitly specify `openssl connect ... -tls1_2` the reply is only `52 00 00 00 0a`, and `web-host` responds `02 46` and `TLS 1.2 Alert, fatal protocol_version`.

I conclude that either `db-host` or MariaDB has an incorrect TLS configuration, as it is not responding to a client-hello handshake message with a server-hello handshake message.  I do not know what to investigate next, as `/etc/my.cnf` on `db-host` appears to be correct.

Comment: Port 3306 for MariaDB/MySQL is not reserved for SSL/TLS; instead it starts in the DBMS protocol and then switches to SSL/TLS. Most SSL/TLS protocols other than HTTPS do this and it is usually called 'starttls' after the switching method used in SMTP[S] (I believe the first). `openssl s_client` supports _some_ starttls protocols using the `-starttls` option; this includes "mysql" only in 1.1.1 and up -- which CentOS8 should have per rpmfind, try (commandline) `openssl version`.

Comment: Alternatively you could try setting sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake` on the Java process and look at the output of that.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 My network has OpenSSL 1.1.1 available.  I installed that on a development system and tried `openssl s_client -starttls mysql ` to reach db-host.  This time a TLS handshake got returned, but the Server Key Exchange errored out with an illegal parameter.

Comment: Using a debugger, look at the contents of the `SSLHandshakeException`. Which MariaDB connecting Java libraries are you using and which version?